# How to refer second classname if two classes have same classname - using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, css, selenium, classname

I would like to get the text(Which is null right now but get some text in future, so printing null should be fine for now) from second "109-top-dark-grey-block ng-binding" class . Tried tabIndex and nth-child both are not working.
"

```
<div class="122-top-section-btm-half">
    <div class="108-top-grey-m12x3"></div>
    <div class="109-top-dark-grey-block ng-binding">ab ab xyz</div>
</div>
```

"
"

```
<div class="d122-top-section-btm-half">
    <div class="108-top-grey-m12x4"></div>
    <div class="109-top-dark-grey-block ng-binding"></div>
```

"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Update

To get the text of the second div block nth-child should work. I tested the selector locally in chrome tools:

[image: nth-child selector working in chrome web tools]

So in your Java:

```
String elementText = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".d122-top-section-btm-half:nth-child(2) .ng-binding")).getText();
```

Should do the trick - as the [CSS spec says nth-child is 1 indexed](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) - not 0 - so its the 2nd child.

## Old Answer

Based on the HTML snippet you provided you could use a CSS selector. So you could do:

```
String elementText = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".d122-top-section-btm-half .109-top-dark-grey-block")).getText();
```

Or if you are just after the element with the ng-binding within your first div then it would be cleaner:

```
String elementText = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".d122-top-section-btm-half .ng-binding")).getText();
```

Both would return the element text - maybe take a look at [CSS Selectors Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors) to learn more.

Comment: Thanks for the response Tom. I am looking for a way to refer second "109-top-dark-grey-block ng-binding"> class. As I mentioned earlier, I have a same heirarchy twice, where I should refer the second class name not the first.

Comment: Hey - I have updated the answer hope it helps. If not my only other suggestion is perhaps your driver is not in the part of the page you think it is.

Comment: Thanks tom. yes, the hierarchy got an other class on top. I took the Unique indicator and implemented the changes as you suggested. Got it working!!